# changing marker camera position in every 10 seconds without refreshing the googlemap

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I'm currently developing an Android app that can track position.
There are two parts of my app:

1. update data (longitude,latitude) to the server
2. receive data from the server every 10 seconds and show it on **googlemap(marker)**

My first part is done and in the second part I am getting a value from the server. But problem arises when I `sync` my map with new values – every time it refreshes the whole map.

If anyone has any insight on how to achieve this effect of being able to run the android app and see the marker dynamically change, it would be much appreciated!

```
public class user_page extends FragmentActivity implements
OnMapReadyCallback {
double longi=0,lati=0;
int id=0;
MapFragment mapFragment;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.tim);

    try
    {
       mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("error",e.toString());
    }
    final Handler h = new Handler();
    h.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            new logincheck().execute();

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"longi = " + longi + "latii = " +lati,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            h.postDelayed(this, 10000);
        }
    }, 10000);


}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


    LatLng current = new LatLng(longi, lati);

    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current, 13));

    googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title(""+id)
            .position(current));



}
// end of class user_page

public class logincheck extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>  {


    HashMap<String, String> data;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataFromdb;

    public logincheck()
    {
        dataFromdb = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    }


    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        id = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder("");
        String line ="";

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("mylink?id=" +id);

        try
        {
            HttpResponse responce = client.execute(httpget);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(responce.getEntity().getContent()));
            while((line= in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                result.append(line);
            }
            in.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.e("error in do in background", e.getMessage());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }


    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mydata = parseJson(result);
        for(int i=0;i < mydata.size();i++)
        {
            longi = Double.parseDouble(mydata.get(i).get("logi"));
            lati = Double.parseDouble(mydata.get(i).get("lati"));

        }
        try {
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(user_page.this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("error",e.toString());
        }

    }

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> parseJson(String stringdata)
    {
        dataFromdb.clear();
        try
        {


            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(stringdata);
            JSONObject jsondata = null;

            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray.length();i++)
            {
                NumberFormat n = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                jsondata = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);
                data.put("logi",jsondata.getString("logi"));
                data.put("lati",jsondata.getString("lati"));

                dataFromdb.add(data);
            }

        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("error in parsing ",e.getMessage());
        }

        return dataFromdb;
    }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use

```
   googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lng), 13));
```

when you receive new lat and lng. This should smoothly animate from current position to new position

Comment: can you give me the edited code i think i am putting it to the wrong place